# Returning public properties of child object

Tags: contract-debugging

I think I'm missing something very simple.  The following contract

```
contract Genobject{
uint public item;
function Genobject(uint _val){
    item=_val;}
}

contract Caller{
   Genobject public instance;
   function Caller(){
       instance= new Genobject(3);
   }
   function Recall() returns (uint){
      return Genobject.item; }
}
```

Gives this error

MultiConstructor.sol:27:16: Error: Member "item" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in type(contract Genobject)

```
    return Genobject.item;
           ^------------^
```

All my types are the same, and "item" is declared publicly so it should be readable.  What's going wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your code, modified:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

contract Genobject {
    uint public item;

    function Genobject(uint _val) {
        item = _val;
    }
}

contract Caller {
   Genobject public instance;

   function Caller() {
       instance = new Genobject(3);
   }

   function recall() constant returns (uint) {
        return instance.item();
   }
}
```

And following is a screenshot of Browser Solidity demonstrating the execution of your contract:

[image]

Here are the changes I made:

1. Renamed `Recall()` to `recall()`.
2. The `recall()` function is marked as `constant` as this function does not modify data, but returns the data.
3. The `recall()` function returns the `item()` value of the `instance` variable rather than the class `Genobject`.
4. `item` is accessed in `recall()` by the automatically generated `item()` public function.

Comment: Is lower case for functions just a style guide or does it have larger ramifications?  Similarly, if I accidentally left out the "constant" keyword would this introduce the possibilities of bugs or is it just to make things read easier?  Thanks

Comment: Lowercase for functions (except for the constructor which must match the class name) is more a style guide. Leaving out constant means that the function is one that modifies data on the blockchain, and therefore will have to be executed as a blockchain transaction rather than a call that just reads the blockchain data. And when your execute a transaction, you get back a transaction hash that you later query to get the transaction details.